# Insert Value of Checkbox (ListView) into Database

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

So this has been bugging me for like a week and I haven't found the answer yet.
Basically I have this MainActivity which contains the main code and a fragment that work for the listview.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private Button bNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new RoomServer(), "Room Server");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

    }
```

**RoomServer.java**

```
public class RoomServer extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{
    public RoomServer() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rs, container,  false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(getListView().CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ArrayAdapter adapter =    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.rs_list,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Fragment_rs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.RoomServer">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bNext_rs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The items of listview r declared inside strings.XML

As u can see I'm using CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE to create checkbox in the listview. And now I'm stuck at how to get the value of this checkbox. I'm planning to use Volley to send value to my database by a button click. Most of the answer I saw was using the isChecked and stuff but I dont really understand how to implement it in my array adapter.

Comment: what you dint understand in ischeckd?

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement a custom array adapter yourself, or use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions()) method in the `ListView` class to get a `SparseBooleanArray` of the indexes of the selected items:

```
//Submit button example
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Get base list
        String[] items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rs_list);

        //Get selected items & set intent args
        SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        ArrayList<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            argList.add(items[selectedItems.keyAt(i)]);
        }

        //Start activity
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("SelectedItems", argList);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I just added the button as a generic example to receive a click event and then update the checked items in the database.  In this example it starts a new activity, but as an alternative you could take the items from the `argList` and update your database.